# curl does not retrieve url. Error (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054

Tags: python, http, ssl, curl, openssl

I need to retrive this site ([www.extra.com.br](https://www.extra.com.br)) in a Python project.

Neither

`page = requests.get("https://www.extra.com.br/")`

nor

`page = requests.get("http://www.extra.com.br/")`

works, the script keeps stuck on this line.

So I went to try using curl to retrieve the page and check it off-line.

`curl http://www.extra.com.br` also does not work. This is the output using -v.

> - STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x6dfd90; line 1392 (connection #-5000)
> - Rebuilt URL to: https://www.extra.com.br/
> - Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
> - STATE: CONNECT => WAITRESOLVE handle 0x6dfd90; line 1428 (connection #0)   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
>     --:--:--     0*   Trying 23.74.196.194...
> - TCP_NODELAY set
> - STATE: WAITRESOLVE => WAITCONNECT handle 0x6dfd90; line 1509 (connection #0)
> - Connected to www.extra.com.br (23.74.196.194) port 443 (#0)
> - STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x6dfd90; line 1561 (connection #0)   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--
>     --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Marked for [keep alive]: HTTP default
> - ALPN, offering h2
> - ALPN, offering http/1.1
> - Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
> - successfully set certificate verify locations:
> - CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt   CApath: none
> - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22): } [5 bytes data]
> - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1): } [512 bytes data]
> - STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => PROTOCONNECT handle 0x6dfd90; line 1575 (connection #0) { [5 bytes data]
> - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2): { [108 bytes data]
> - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11): { [2799 bytes data]
> - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12): { [333 bytes data]
> - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14): { [4 bytes data]
> - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16): } [70 bytes data]
> - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1): } [1 bytes data]
> - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20): } [16 bytes data]
> - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1): { [1 bytes data]
> - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20): { [16 bytes data]
> - SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
> - ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> - Server certificate:
> - subject: C=BR; ST=Sao Paulo; L=Sao Paulo; O=CNOVA Comercio Eletronico S.A.; OU=TI; CN=*.extra.com.br
> - start date: Jul 17 00:00:00 2018 GMT
> - expire date: Jul 17 12:00:00 2019 GMT
> - subjectAltName: host "www.extra.com.br" matched cert's "*.extra.com.br"
> - issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
> - SSL certificate verify ok.
> - STATE: PROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x6dfd90; line 1596 (connection #0) } [5 bytes data]
>
>   > GET / HTTP/1.1
>   >     Host: www.extra.com.br
>   >     User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
>   >     Accept: */*
> - STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x6dfd90; line 1658 (connection #0)
> - STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x6dfd90; line 1783 (connection #0)
> - STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x6dfd90; line 1799 (connection #0)   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:19 --:--:--     0* OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054
> - Marked for [closure]: Transfer returned error
> - multi_done
> - stopped the pause stream!   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:19 --:--:--     0
> - Closing connection 0
> - The cache now contains 0 members } [5 bytes data] curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054

Comment: In short: the site is protected by Akamai bot detection. One need to set specific HTTP headers correctly to work around this detection.